# É possível passar parâmetros de uma rota para outra sem ser pela url em reactjs?

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Eu estou aprendendo reactjs e na aplicação que estou desenvolvendo tenho uma tela de login que faz a autenticação do usuario para ele acessar uma rota privada. Nessa rota privada eu gostaria de carregar os dados desse usuario numa header perfil e posteriormente executar algumas operações em outras telas com o log desse usuário. É possível passar passar algum parametro para essa rota privada sem ser do tipo "rota/:email" ou "rota/:idUsuario" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [redux](https://redux.js.org/) para salvar dados na [store](https://redux.js.org/api/store) no momento em que você troca de route (De maneira que os dados estarão acessíveis nas outras telas). Similarmente, você pode utilizar do [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router), que já salva dados da route utilizando o redux internamente (De maneira que se passar dados na URL, poderá acessá-los na outra tela).

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde Lury Felipe,

Cara, tem dois métodos de mandar parâmetros:

> GET e POST

O método `GET` é passado por URL, exemplo `www.google.com/user=CiclanoDaSilva`.

Já o `POST` é passado por um corpo de requisição, sendo possivel por exemplo mandar um JSON no corpo.

Espero ter ajudado você!!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, Rodrigo, mas acho que você não entendeu minha dúvida. Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal. Meu objetivo é  fazer um login de usuario pra autenticar e liberar acesso a uma rota privada sem que essa rota fique to tipo "https://dominio/rota/idUsuario", mas simplesmente "rota/" não deixando o usuário acessar o id de outra pessoa sendo o que o mesmo está autenticado.